# icons not appearing in visual studio?

Tags: fonts, icons, font-awesome

```
@model IEnumerable<Reci_me.BL.Models.Category>

<body onload="ChangeIcon()">
  <ul>
        @foreach (var category in Model)
        {
            @*<div id="icon">@category.Name</div>*@
           <li onload="ChangeIcon()">
                <i id="icon" class="fa" style="font-size: 20px;color:black;"></i>
                <a id="iconName" 
                   asp-controller="Recipe"
                   asp-action="Browse"
                   asp-route-id="@category.Id">@category.Name</a>
           </li>
        }
    </ul>
@*    <h1 id="icon"></h1>*@
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    function ChangeIcon() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById("iconName").innerHTML == "American") 
            {
                document.getElementById("icon").classList.add("fa-hotdog");
            }else if (document.getElementById("iconName").innerHTML == "Greek") 
            {
                document.getElementById("icon").classList.add("fa-fish");
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("iconName").innerHTML == "Italian") 
            {
                document.getElementById("icon").classList.add("fa-pizza-slice");
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("iconName").innerHTML == "Mexican") 
            {
                document.getElementById("icon").classList.add("fa-pepper-hot");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OAcB.png)

this is how it looks currently, please help. been working on this for a couple of days now, need help. building a recipe page, you know what I'm talking about.